# Spring: How to override class used in @Import annotation

Tags: java, spring, filter, import

I have to override function getMyObject, from class Server:

```
@EnableResourceServer
public class Server extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{   //class from library
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http){
        ....
        addFilterBefore(getMyObject(),anotherArgument);
        ...
    }
    
    protected Filter getMyObject(){
        return new CustomFilter();
    }
}


@Import({ Server.class })  
public class Config{  //class from library

    public void someMethod(){}
}


public class ConfigExt extends Config{   // my class

    @Override
    public void someMethod(){ // my implementation}

}
```

I tried to extends Server class and override getMyObject method. Next I added @Import ServerExt to ConfigExt class:

```
@EnableResourceServer
public class ServerExt extends Server{   // my class
        
    @Override
    protected Filter getMyObject(){
        return new CustomFilterExt();  
    }
}

@Import({ ServerExt.class }) 
public class ConfigExt extends Config{   // my class

    @Override
    public void someMethod(){ // my implementation}

}
```

But it cause that 2 instances are created: Server and ServerExt. Therefore both CustomFilter and CustomFilterExt are launched.

So above solution does not work. How can I deal with it ?

Comment: What version of `spring-security-oauth2` do you use?

Comment: It is 2.2.0.RELEASE.

Comment: What library is `Server` and `Config` from? Looks like it don't support what you want.

Comment: It is our internal library , written by other team.

Comment: I think you better ask them then. They may need to make some changes to make it possible.

Comment: Therefore from spring perspective there is no possibility to override @Import class for my own class?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but pretty confident in it. As long as bean in question doesn't have some annotation to turn it on it will be instantiated and put in context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220859/discussion-between-lucas999-and-talex).